# How to do indexing in a collection of 400 Million (40 crores) data in mongob?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database, nosql

I know how to do indexing in mongodb but unable to do indexing in very big collection.

As my collections consists of 400 million data, then its very difficult to fetch the data (almost impossible )

I know mongodb do indexing by default in _id field but not able to fetch the data from the database using the _id field. I tried to create indexing but somehow unable to do it. The I try in less amount of data approx. 20 million (2 crores), then I am able to indexing but unable to fetch the result again.

Following command using for create indexing :-

```
db.collectionname.createIndex( { registration: 1 } );
```

So how can I fetch the record from these heavy collections.

I hope I am able to elaborate and explain my question

Thanks in advance

Comment: please give us more details about the sizing of your mongodb cluser. Did you make profiling how does the cpu, load, ram usage look like when performing a query?

Comment: I didn't look to these things but when I run a query it takes 20-30 minutes and still going on